# JavaScript carousel function with next and back issues

Tags: javascript, html, image, carousel

I am having a small issue with my code. I am sure something is missing but I can't figure it out. When I want to go to the previous image , it goes actually to the next one , and after that it's going back...

I willl share the code with you , thanks a lot..been trying for an hour to find the issue but can't find what's wrong...thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Practica</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <style>
  *{margin:0;padding:0;}
  html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
   }
    #mainImage{
    width:50%;
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
     }
    a{
      color:white;
     font-size:60px;
     text-decoration:none;
       }

    .next {
     position:absolute;
      top:500px;
      right:0px;
      }

    .back {
      position:absolute;
      top:500px;
      left:0px;}
    </style>
    </head>


   <body>
     <div id="mainImage" style="background:url(images/unu.jpg)">
     <a href="#" class="back" onclick="backImage()">&#10096;</a>
     <a href="#" class="next" onclick="nextImage()">&#10097;</a>

     </div>

     </body>


      </html>
```

JS

```
   var imageArray = ["background:url(images/unu.jpg)", 
    "background:url(images/doi.jpg)", "background:url(images/trei.jpg)", 
    "background:url(images/patru.jpg)", "background:url(images/cinci.jpg)"];
    var imageIndex = 1;

    function nextImage() {
     var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
     myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]);  
     imageIndex++;
     if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
       imageIndex = 0;
       }

     }

    function backImage(){
      var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
      myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]); 
      imageIndex--;
      if (imageIndex < 0){
      imageIndex = imageArray.length;
       }
    }
```

Comment: `myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]); ` should go after `imageIndex--` or `imageIndex++` and `imageIndex=` otherwise your `nextImage` or `backImage` function is doing what the previous clicked button's action was.

Answer (score 0):

Increase/decrease the index before you set the image from the index:

```
function nextImage() {
  imageIndex++;
  var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
  myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]);
```

Do the same with the `backImage`.

Answer (score 0):

This function has the problem with the logic

```
function backImage(){
      var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
      myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]); 
      imageIndex--;
      if (imageIndex < 0){
      imageIndex = imageArray.length;
       }
    }
```

let say initially you are at 0th image i.e imageIndex=1 and once you click on next

function nextImage() will set 1st image and imageIndex will be 2 now as below:

```
function backImage(){
          //imageIndex is 2 now
          var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
          myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]); //load 3rd image i.e 2nd indexed image  //it should be 1st ideally
          imageIndex--; //decrease imageIndex to 1
          if (imageIndex < 0){
          imageIndex = imageArray.length;
           }
        }
```

So your code must be

```
imageIndex--;
myImage.setAttribute("style",imageArray[imageIndex]);
```